# Cuda and Nsight - launch

Tags: cuda, launch, nsight

I've successfully installed Cuda SDK and tested the compiler with an HelloWorld
Then I've opened Nsight and I've tried with the same code.
I got this answer " Launch Failed. Binary not found." Is this a problem of the compiler involved in Nsight?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug. We are aware of it and will try to fix it in one of our future releases.

You need to manually build the project at least once before starting the debug - this is needed for the debugger to be able to detect executable and setup all settings. Note that the debugger will automatically trigger the build on subsequent runs - when it already knows the executable and build configuration you are using..

Comment: what do you mean by "manually build the project" ? How can I do that?

thanks

Comment: You need to click the hammer button on a main toolbar - or right-click the project and select Build.